# start tomcat without correct catalina directory

Tags: java, tomcat

I've encountered an issue with tomcat. I'm so sorry because I cannot provide any image for some specific reasons. In general, I executed

```
ps -ef | grep Dcatalina.home
```

to find instances of tomcat, I got some. There is one instance that has

```
-classpath /path-to-directory/bin/bootstrap.jar 
-Dcatalina.base=/path-to-directory 
-Dcataline.home=/path-to-directory,
```

but when I use

```
ls -lia /path-to-directory
```

the directory has no file or directory other than logs directory.
My question: is it possible to start tomcat like this, or some kind activity happened after the normal start of tomcat?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.  Are you having a hard tims finding the location of the Tomcat `bin/` directory?

Comment: What I want to point out here is can tomcat start with Dcatalina home with no bin directory.

Comment: Tomcat usually launches from the `catalina` start script.  You can launch anywhere so long as you have the Tomcat binaries somewhere.

Comment: @thangnv are you using something like spring boot? or embedded tomcat?